# How to show Timer's remaining time in all activities?

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I want to create a CountDownTimer passing its remaining time through all activities and show it in TextViews. I tried using `intent.putExtra` but when i start the new Activity the Timer restarts.

This is what I need:

> -ActivityA starts with a 60 seconds timer, so its TextView shows 59...58...57...etc...
>
> -ActivityB starts after 6 seconds so its TextView shows 54...53...52...etc...

The Countdown simply have to go on from first to last activity.

Hope I was clear enough.
Thank you for solutions and sorry for my Ital-English.

Answer (score 1):

use a static variable (maybe create a new class for "better" code).

```
public static int time;
```

Or you can declare it in your ActivityA, count the variable down and use it in ActivityB

```
textView.setText("" + ActivityA.time);
```

EDIT:

```
public class MyTimer {
    private static int time = 60;

    public MyTimer() {
        if(time >= 60) {
            countDown();  //let countDown only run once
        }
    }

    private void countDown() {
         //insert a thread here, which counts your time down
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }

}
```

And then, in your acitivities:

```
MyTimer mTimer = new MyTimer();
textview.setText(mTimer.getTime() + "");
```

Comment: So can I create an independent Class with the Timer and only set TextViews in all activities?

Comment: yeah, thats the best idea! Create an independend class, in it: store the static variable (so the value is in every activity the same), count it down and call the variables value from your activities.

Comment: When I start my App textView = time:null

Comment: I edited my anser, all you have to do is to implement the thread by yourself.

Comment: The countdown that I created works well but when I start ActivityB from ActivityA the textView shows this: "android.widget.TextView@4051bde8" instead of remaining time

Comment: then you didn't set the text correctly... Try to copy the textview-code you have in ActivitA... it should look somehow like `myTextView.setText(timer.getTime() + "");`